# WPF DataGrid cell foreground binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcell

I am trying to change a column's Foreground color according to its value. When I try to set the Foreground statically it works but when I use binding with a converter nothing happens.

Here is a small example

```
<DataGrid Foreground="White" FontSize="13" x:Name="datagrid_results" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridTable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3,5,1.6,35" MaxHeight="260">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Header="Minimum" Binding="{Binding Minimum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Header="Maximum" Binding="{Binding Maximum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" Header="Pass-Fail" Binding="{Binding Pass_Fail, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Pass_Fail , Converter={StaticResource s2b}}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is my Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    Brush myBrush = Brushes.White;
    string input = value as string;
    switch (input)
    {
        case "Pass":
            myBrush = Brushes.LightGreen;
            break;
        case "Fail":
            myBrush = Brushes.Red;
            break;
        default:
            myBrush = Brushes.White;
            break;
    }

    return myBrush;
}
```

The weird thing is that when debugging this converter, the brush is returning the correct value. It's just the the cell is not changing its text color. However when I used this:`<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />` my cells change their text color. Is there anything that I might be missing?

With static color:
[image: Static Color]

With dynamic color:
[image: Dynamic Color]

Comment: You can remove , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged off your bindings. Read up on what they do. Generally speaking, I would suggest you only put markup in that you understand. Start with a minimum and only change that when you see problems. Even then, don't just paste stuff in without understanding what it will do.

Comment: Put a break point in your converter and spin it up to see what's happening. Prove it hits your converter and step through. Is it definitely a string you get? What value have you got for the first one? What path does the code take as you step through?  Prove what it's going to return. If it's correct then your foreground property is set and it's something like dependency property precedence is your issue. If it's not correct then fix it. Either way you narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]>

> ```
> DataGrid Foreground="White" FontSize="13" x:Name="datagrid_results"
> AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsClass,
>  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3,5,1.6,35"
> MaxHeight="260">
> <DataGrid.Columns>
>     <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Header="Minimum" Binding="{Binding Minimum, Mode=TwoWay,
> UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
>     <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Header="Maximum" Binding="{Binding Maximum, Mode=TwoWay,
> UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
>     <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" Header="Pass-Fail" Binding="{Binding Pass_Fail, Mode=TwoWay,
> UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
>         <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
>             <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
>                 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Pass_Fail , Converter={StaticResource s2b}}" />
>             </Style>
>         </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
>     </DataGridTextColumn>
> </DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>
> ```

Remove Mode=TwoWay from your datagrid first line of xaml

> ```
>  public partial class MainWindow : Window
>     {
>         List<ItemsClass> items = new List<ItemsClass>();
>         public MainWindow()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>             this.DataContext = this;
>             items.Add(new ItemsClass()
>             {
>                 Pass_Fail="Pass"
>             });
>             items.Add(new ItemsClass()
>             {
>                 Pass_Fail = "Fail"
>             });
>             items.Add(new ItemsClass()
>             {
>                 Pass_Fail = "Pass"
>             });
>             items.Add(new ItemsClass()
>             {
>                 Pass_Fail = "Fail"
>             });
>             datagrid.ItemsSource = items;
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: ok. i used your code. and it works when i remove mode=twoway

Answer (score 1):

I have been used to make things works even if it is not the way I was doing so if you need this to work fast I can offer you an alternative while the perfect solution is coming.
To make thing works I simply used a boolean and the triggers.

```
         <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding pass}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding pass}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

So in this exemple (I didn't modify so much), I change the background color according to the pass value (which is simply a boolean).

Comment: I was able to get what I want using your example, with a little change where I used a string to boolean converter. Yet I was unable to find what was the problem in my approach.

Comment: Yes, that's the point i wanted to give you an alternative so you can move forward. I hope someone will find how to get your method works